# join 2 flash banners without decompiling?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have 2 banners on my site that change on refresh, the clients wants 1 banner to start after another, is there any way to do this without decompiling them? decomplining is out of the question because both banners use fonts that aren't publicly available (company fots) and banners are ruined after opening in flash. I tried importing swf files directly in flash but still have the same problem with fonts. anyone have any idea how can i do this?

Comment: not sure how much control you have over the banners and if you can use multiple swfs. one option is to have a main swf which loads the two and keeps track of the current frame in the main timeline or something. once the 1st loaded swf plays the loader swf plays the second.

Comment: I cant open them in flash, I only have swf s , I am not to decompile or trigger with them in any way...

Comment: I didn't say open them in flash, I said load them (in actionscript), but not sure if you're allowed to load files in the swf (some banner hosting site don't allow loading any external files, other do). For as2 look at [MovieClipLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7d08.html), for as3 look at [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)